# Functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ that are injective but not surjective, and vice versa

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are sets each containing the same finite number of elements and $f: A \to B$.
>
> a. Prove that $f$ is injective if and only if it is surjective.
>
> b. Give an example of an injective function from $\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ that is not surjective. Does this contradict (a)?
>
> c. Give an example of a surjective function from $\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ that is not injective. Does this contradict (a)?

**My attempts**

b. $f(x)= \frac{x}{2}$

c. $f(x) = x -1$

I don't get if it contradict part a.

Comment: **Attention**: To all that downvote this question: Leave a comment explaining why.  It's completely ridiculous for you to use this (in my opinion totally useless) voting system if you don't intend to help improve content by commenting your suggested changes.  It's not rocket science......

Comment: I think you need to revise your understanding of the term "function".  The answers you have given are not actually functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$, so the properties "injective" and "surjective" do not apply.

Answer (score 4):

It may be that the downvotes are because your work does not even exhibit that you understand the concepts of injective and surjective, the definitions of which you may well be expected to use in your answers for b) and c).

Both of your answers are dead-wrong: the function listed in b) is NOT from $\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ (it has the wrong co-domain). For example, $f(1) = \frac{1}{2}$ is NOT a natural number.

The function you give in c) IS surjective, but it also is injective, To see this, suppose:

$f(x) = f(y) \implies x - 1 = y - 1 \implies (x - 1) + 1 = (y - 1) + 1 \implies x = y$.

(EDIT: as pointed out in the comments, $f$ is not even a function from $\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$, as one can see by noting $f(0) = -1 \not\in \Bbb N$).

I suggest you try some function $f$ for b) that "skips" values in $\Bbb N$, you want "gaps" in the co-domain. For c), you might try using the floor function, somehow.

a) is the most important question, here though. Finiteness is key, that's what b) and c) are supposed to convince you of. Start by assuming $f$ is surjective. What happens if you assume (by way of contradiction), that $f$ is not injective? (hint: compare the cardinalities of the range, and the domain).

Comment: Actually, (c) is not a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Indeed it is not, mt bad!

Answer (score 1):

$a)$: Since $f$ is injective, $|A| = |f(A)|$, and $|A|=|B|$, so $|f(A)| = |B|$, and since both $|f(A)|, |B|$ are finite,and more over $f(A) \subseteq B$, we deduce that $f(A) = B$, hence $f$ is surjective.

Conversely, if $f$ is surjective, we prove it is injective. Suppose that $f$ is not injective, then $|A| > |f(A)|$, and since $|A| = |B| \Rightarrow |f(A)| < |B| = |B \setminus f(A)| + |f(A)| \Rightarrow |B\setminus f(A)| > 0 \Rightarrow B\setminus f(A) \neq \emptyset$, and both $B$, and $f(A)$ are finite, it must be that $f(A) \neq B \Rightarrow f$ is not surjective, contradiction. So $f$ is injective.

$b)$: Take $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$: $f(1) = 2, f(2) = 3, \cdots , f(n) = n+1$ is injective but not surjective.

$c)$: Take $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$: $f(1) = f(2) = 1, f(3) = 2, f(4) = 3,\cdots f(n) = n - 1$ is surjective but not injective.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}$ in (b) is not a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, as $f(1) = \frac{1}{2} \not\in \mathbb{N}$. Still, it has the spirit of a correct answer: For which values $\lambda$ does the rule $x \mapsto \lambda x$ define a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$? For which of these $\lambda$ is it injective? Surjective?

Likewise, the function in (c) again is not a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. If your convention is $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$, then $f(0) = -1 \not\in \mathbb{N}$. On the other hand, $0$ is the only value of $x$ for which $f(x) \not\in \mathbb{N}$, so you can modify this example to produce a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by choosing some $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and defining
$$
f(x) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
        a, & x = 0 \\
    x - 1, & x \in \mathbb{N} - \{0\}
\end{array}
\right. .
$$
Is this function injective? Surjective? (Sometimes $\mathbb{N}$ is taken to be $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$, in which case the above comments can be modified readily.)

Comment: f(x) = 2x is injective and not surjective then? and ceiling of x/2 is surjective but not injective?

Comment: Yes, that's correct---can you prove it?

Comment: If 2x=2y, x=y. it's not surjective because 2x=3, and 3/2 is not a natural number. ceiling of x/2 is not injective because f(2) = f(1). surjective because f(x) is always a natural number for ceiling functions.

Comment: Everything looks good except for the last remark: That the ceiling function always returns a natural number doesn't alone guarantee that $x \mapsto \left\lceil \frac{x}{2} \right\rceil$ is surjective, but can construct an explicit element that this function maps to any given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, namely $2n$, as we have $\left\lceil \frac{(2n)}{2} \right\rceil = \lceil n \rceil = n$.

Comment: OK, I think I get now. So both contradict a because for both functions, |A| = |B|? I don't get how |A| = |B| because there are gaps in codomain though?

Comment: No, neither contradict because $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite. As for $|A| = |B|$, this is possible for infinite sets. In general we declare $A, B$ to have the same cardinality if there is a bijection between the two, and it is possible for an infinite set to be in bijection with a proper subset, but this is not possible for finite sets.

Comment: I dont understand. The codomains of functions in b and c are proper subsets of the infinite set of natural numbers? But there is no bijection between the proper subsets and infinite set of natural numbers? Because we found injective not surjective, and surjective not injective types of functions.

Comment: One of the hypotheses of (a) is that the involved sets are finite. In (b) and (c) the involved sets (all $\mathbb{N}$) are infinite, so (a) does not apply, hence there is no contradiction.

In your example for (b), namely the map $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $x \mapsto 2x$, the map is not a bijection, but it *is* a bijection onto its image, namely the set $2 \mathbb{N}$ of even numbers in $\mathbb{N}$. Thus, $\mathbb{N}$ and $2 \mathbb{N}$ have the same cardinality, despite that the latter is a proper subset of the former.

Comment: OK I think that make sense now. Thanks you.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

a) As $f$ is injective, each element of $A$ is uniquely mapped to an element of $B$. As $|A|=|B|$, there is no element of $B$ that is un-used, or used twice. Hence $f$ is surjective. With |A|=|B| and $|A|$ finite, we can merely reverse the argument to prove surjective implies injective. Hence $f$ is both  injective or surjective, so it is a bijection.

b) $f(x)=2x$ is injective but not surjective

c) $f(x)=\lfloor{x/2}\rfloor$ is surjective but not injective

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) explains injective and surjective well.

Comment: c) should be $ f(x)=\lceil{x/2}\rceil $ i guess, as $ 0 \notin \mathbb N$

Comment: @OleksandrKhryplyvenko; it's debated:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

Answer (score 0):

a.) Use the definitions you know. $f$ is injective if $f(n_1) = f(n_2) \implies n_1 = n_2, \forall {n_1,n_2} \in \mathbb{N}$. $f$ surjective if the image matches the domain, that $f(A) = [b \in B \space | \space \forall b \in B, \exists a \in A \space s.t. f(a) = b]$.

Here's the intuitive proof:

So suppose $f$ injective, so that every value in A is matched with a unique element in B. But A and B have the same number of finite elements. So that means the image of A is simply all elements in B, so surjection holds, that $f(A) = B$

Suppose $f$ surjective, so that every element in the codomain B is matched with an element in the domain A. But by definition of a function, multiple elements in B can't be matched with the same element in A. Since A and B have the same number of elements, every element in B is associated with a unique element in A, and injection holds.

b, c.) You have to make a function so that the the number of elements in A and B aren't the same. So something silly like $f(x) = 2x$ for $x$ between 1 and 10 for the domain and codomain. This is injective, but not surjective, because not every element in the codomain is in the image.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sets $A$ and $B$ have the same finite cardinality.
2. Since $f$ is a function, then every element in $A$ maps *once* to some element in $B$.
3. $f$ will be injective iff every element in $A$ maps *exclusively* to an element in $B$ (no other element in $A$ maps to that element).
4. $f$ will be surjective iff every element in $B$ is mapped to by an element in $A$.

Use these definitions to prove that $f$ is injective, if and only if, $f$ is surjective.